# Solr "possible analysis error" -- unclear cause

Tags: solr

I have a schema in `schema.xml` similar to the following MWE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema name="myschema" version="1.6">

  <field name="_version_" type="plong" indexed="false" stored="false"/>

  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
  <field name="id" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>

  <field name="content" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" uninvertible="false" required="true"/>
  
  <!--
  (definitions and dynamicFields for boolean, date, strings, double, text_general, float, 
  int, long, random, ignored, binary and rank)
  -->

  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" docValues="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_s" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  
  <fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer name="standard"/>
      <filter name="stop" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"/>
      <filter name="lowercase"/>
      <filter name="englishPossessive"/>
      <filter protected="protwords.txt" name="keywordMarker"/>
      <filter name="porterStem"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer name="standard"/>
      <filter name="synonymGraph" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter name="stop" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"/>
      <filter name="lowercase"/>
      <filter name="englishPossessive"/>
      <filter protected="protwords.txt" name="keywordMarker"/>
      <filter name="porterStem"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_en" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

</schema>
```

However, performing a basic `update` such as the following:

```
{
    "content": "aaaa",
    "id": "aaaa"
}
```

Fails with the error message:

> Exception writing document id aaaa to the index; possible analysis error.

This seems to usually mean that I'm adding something incompatible with the schema. Clearly, this is not the case here. It suggests that perhaps the syntax of the schema is flawed, but usually that results in its own error.

What's going on here?

Comment: Okay, so... this gets _really_ weird. It ONLY happens when I have a manually set `schema.xml` as opposed to a `managed-schema.xml`. That's extremely unusual.